# Нужно решить проблему с копированием файла в диски python

Tags: python, python-3.9, shutil

Мне нужно чтобы мой код при запуске автоматически определял буквы дисков, которые есть на компьютере у пользователя и копировал туда текстовый файл, желательно чтобы после этого сразу копировал в каждом диске в каждую папку и подпапку этот же текстовый файл

```
import os
import sys
import shutil
import time

file = open("Открой меня.txt", "w")
file.write("Hello World")
file.close()

time.sleep(7)

def function_global():
    try:
        def function1():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'Q:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function1()
        function1()
        
        def function2():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'R:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function2()
        function2()
        
        def function3():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'E:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function3()
        function3()
        
        def function4():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'W:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function4()
        function4()
        
        def function5():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'T:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function5()
        function5()
        
        def function6():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'Y:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function6()
        function6()
        
        def function7():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'U:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function7()
        function7()
        
        def function8():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'I:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function8()
        function8()
        
        def function9():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'O:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function9()
        function9()
        
        def function10():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'P:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function10()
        function10()
        
        def function11():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'A:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function11()
        function11()
        
        def function12():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'S:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function12()
        function12()
        
        def function13():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'D:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function13()
        function13()
        
        def function14():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'F:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function14()
        function14()
        
        def function15():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'G:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function15()
        function15()
        
        def function16():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'H:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function16()
        function16()
        
        def function17():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'J:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function17()
        function17()
        
        def function18():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'K:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function18()
        function18()
        
        def function19():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'L:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function19()
        function19()
        
        def function20():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'Z:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function20()
        function20()
        
        def function21():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'X:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function21()
        function21()
        
        def function22():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'V:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function22()
        function22()
        
        def function23():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'B:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function23()
        function23()
        
        def function24():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'N:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function24()
        function24()
        
        def function25():
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('Открой меня.txt', 'M:/Открой меня.txt')
            except:
                function25()
        function25()
        
    except:
        function_global()
function_global()
```

к сожалению код не работает должным образом, если в первой функций есть буква моего диска, то он делает копирование, если же поменять на любую другую букву диска, который у меня не создан, тогда он не копирует, а просто завершает программу

Comment: Ну вы и намудрили.. [Тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/827397/1105714) похожий вопрос

Comment: Пожалуйста, не делайте так больше. Это все равно, что для каждого математического выражения прописывать результаты `print("1*1 =", 1*1)`, `print("1*2=", 1*2)` и т.д.

Comment: Не забывайте про принцип DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself. Имя файла вынесите в переменную, например `filename`, и используйте в любом месте программы.

Comment: спасибо, я понял как решить вопрос с обнаружением дисков, но я не смог понять как копировать один и тот же файл в корень всех имеющихся дисков

Comment: А в чем проблема? Что вы не можете?

Comment: я понял как сделать обнаружение дисков и сделал их в переменную "disks" . Но я не знаю как теперь сделать так чтобы копирование файла происходило во все диска. Переменная disks выдаёт такой результат: [Q:\\, D:\\, R:\\, C:\\] 
В итоге он копирует только в первый диск Q при всех попытках

Comment: Ну вы по списку проходите и для каждого элемента копируйте файл функцией `copyfile()` в корневой каталог, не вижу ничего сложного